# Handling post and session values in form submit PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, if-statement, isset

I have a code like this.
What I'm trying to do is:

1. Check whether post values is there, if yes - execute my query and display the result.
2. Or check for session value, if session is there play with session value and display the result.

When I print the session value, it is getting printed (i.e `author_id` is there in session) 
But it is not coming inside the IF loop. Why?

In other words, I want to check for post values or session value, and display the record accordingly.

PS: If i remove the `||` condition  (i.e `isset ( $_SESSION ['author_id']` ) ) my code words perfect.

```
    <?php 
    session_start();
    print_r($_SESSION);
    if (isset ( $_POST ['submit'] )  ||  isset ( $_SESSION ['author_id'] )) {   

        .. do something with my post values or session values ..

    }
    ?>

    <form method="post" id="myform1" name="myform1">
    ........... my form fields..............
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Important: Instead of using session or cookie, is there a way to handle the form input field values in the same page?

Comment: try `print_r($_POST);` to check the post values

Comment: even i'm getting the post values too .. any help.

Comment: You never go inside the if statement ? Your condition seems to work.

Comment: Hey it's working fine on me, use `&&` instead of `||` to check both the `$_SESSION` and `$_POST`

Comment: check it here http://runnable.com/me/U_Hs--xhLLAIpotT

Comment: @JothiKannan - i don't want to check both. I need to check any one (i.e post or session) .. so only

Comment: @JothiKannan - the link you provided doesn't work

Comment: ok, check it here http://web-4884085a-e432-4099-a0f7-9a1cff2ac8e3.runnable.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try check with Only $_POST

```
if (isset( $_POST)||isset ( $_SESSION ['author_id'] )) {   

        .. do something with my post values or session values ..

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value to java script function in `onclick()` and you can do certain amount of processing in that function